# What does "by taking God at His Word" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context:

> Can we be sure of our salvation? One day a young woman asked for prayer. She told me that when she accepted Christ as her Savior she had felt so wonderful, so full of joy. Now she didn’t feel that way and wanted to know why she had “lost her salvation.” We know that we are not saved by feeling, but by taking God at His Word.

Comment: If you want a meaning in context, in might help to produce more context (a link would be ideal).

Comment: The meaning of *"take [someone] at their word"* is General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers See comment in answer below about combining phrases. The capitalization indicates there is more going on here, specifically an allusion.

Comment: @kmarsh: The context is overtly Christian. Even those who know little of that religion know *Word of God=Bible*. And who could fail to register the significance of OP's capitalisation? Anyone who *didn't* understand would have been stymied much earlier, since they also wouldn't have a clue what *"asked for prayer"* or *"accepted Christ as her Savior"* meant.

Comment: The OP said the quote was from an email, so the capitalization was copied from there. Reading the FAQ I see discussing Christian usages is not prohibited, but then again neither is arbitrary downvotes.

Comment: -1 Religious examples are perfectly fine. Posting a question with research not shown isn't. Google searches `[ define take God at His Word ]` and `[ define take at his word ]` provide many starting points for online research.

Comment: Yes, Google, properly used, can help one find an answer to any question here... so let's see that "single link to a standard internet reference source". I'm thinking Google is NOT a "standard reference source". It's a standard referral source.

Answer (score 2):

The statement first implies acceptance of the Bible as literally correct ("We know") Holy Writ (by capitalizing "Word", corresponding to the English usage in the Gospel of John), then states that promises and conditions made in the biblical canon concerning salvation of the soul (from hell, consequences of sin, etc.) supersede personal convictions of status based on emotional feelings.

The statement attempts to separate emotional certainty ("I feel saved") from intellectual conviction ("I meet the biblical criteria for salvation"). Many Christian philosophers debate whether such separation is necessary, beneficial, or even possible.

Comment: I'd just note, in case it wasn't totally clear from the details, that *taking someone at their word* generally means to believe what they say.

Comment: You're right, the sentence end somewhat cleverly combines  combines two phrases, "His Word" (meaning biblical Canon) and "taking someone at their word".